# Creating and using a bootable USB for a new build

Tags: boot

I'm brand new to building computers and just finished putting together a decent CAD machine.  Now I'm looking for an operating system, I have no previous system installed and was wondering how the process works for a fresh computer? I have access to a Mac laptop and plenty of empty USB sticks.

Comment: While CAD programs like AutoCAD, Rhino 3D, SketchUp, SolidWorks, etc will work on a virtual machine within Ubuntu, they will be very slow. I have not found a good CAD program that works directly with Ubuntu. CAD is the main reason that I still use Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a bootable usb.

Just download the .iso of the operating system you want to use and load it onto a usb with something like 4gb or more of storage capacity.

I'm not sure what apple uses to create a bootable usb, but I know in ubuntu you would use a program called Startup Disk Creator.

1) Download the .iso file
2) plug in the usb 
3) launch Startup Disk Creator 
4) you will then be prompted to select the usb you want to use and the .iso file you downloaded previously
5) It will take a while for the process to complete, and once it's done unplug your usb and plug it in when restarting the computer you would like to load the Operating System on

Hope this helps

Comment: Appreciate it. Just to clarify, there is no need to have some earlier operating system in play i can download the most current form of ubuntu and then boot my brand new build.